# Nodejs and expressjs. Ajax get request not returning data

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Api in JS:

```
router.route('/books')
    .get(function(req,res){
         Repository.getAll().done( function(result){ res.json(result);},function(err){res.send(err);}); 
    })
    .post(function(req,res){
         Repository.save(req.body).done( function(object){ res.json(object); },function(err){res.send("error seems to have occured");});
    });
```

which works fine when I post using Fiddler and get using chrome browser. But when I attempt to get and post using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "http://localhost:8000/api/books",
                                data: { "title":"My name is","releaseYear":"1989","director":"me","genre":"horror" }
                            }).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Success.");
                            console.log("success");
                        }).error(function(data, err, e, o) {

                            console.log("error");
                            //alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                        });

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET", 
                                url: "http://localhost:8000/api/books",
                                contentType: "application/json"
                            }).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Success.");
                            console.log("success");
                        }).error(function(data, err, e, o) {

                            console.log("error");
                            //alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                        });
```

Fail/ error callback is fired. I've tried specifying the contentType or removing it but to no avail.

When calling POST, the status code is 200 but no data is returned and calls fail function

Comment: your request is calling "/api/books" and you are listening only "/books"

Comment: Did you debugged both client and server results to sure it has any data?

Comment: İlker Korkut: Debugging the server would be a mission as ive never debugged node before. Nada: that is not the case. The url I am calling is correct

Comment: @user1809104 install node-inspector to debug your applicaton. Here it is https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Answer (score 2):

your request is calling "/api/books" and you are listening only "/books"

Modify your client code request url to that:

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "http://localhost:8000/books",
                                data: { "title":"My name is","releaseYear":"1989","director":"me","genre":"horror" }
                            }).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Success.");
                            console.log("success");
                        }).error(function(data, err, e, o) {

                            console.log("error");
                            //alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                        });

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET", 
                                url: "http://localhost:8000/books",
                                contentType: "application/json"
                            }).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Success.");
                            console.log("success");
                        }).error(function(data, err, e, o) {

                            console.log("error");
                            //alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                        });
```

Or modify your server code to that:

```
router.route('/api/books')
    .get(function(req,res){
         Repository.getAll().done( function(result){ res.json(result);},function(err){res.send(err);}); 
    })
    .post(function(req,res){
         Repository.save(req.body).done( function(object){ res.json(object); },function(err){res.send("error seems to have occured");});
    });
```

Comment: May be he is using prefixed routers `app.use('/api', router);` ?

Comment: so maybe is better specify this in his question :D

Comment: The correct url to call is: http://localhost:8000/api/books. I am using prefixed routers. As stated, this seems to work everywhere else but when called using jquery

Comment: @user1809104 do a `console.log(json(result));` or `console.log(json(object));` on your server to see if result is null on your server. Delete "http://localhost:8000" from your ajax URL. Check console errors for CORs or something like that. Just check if the request reaches the server and what is the server response (on the server side)

Comment: Nada: using http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/books', function (http_res) {
} I am able to get results calling it from server side. I can also making the request from chrome with no issues. the error that comes back simple says "error" in the fail callback. There would be no need to console.log anything because it works else where

Comment: I have just checked and the CORS access is not granted. I have however placed this in app.js: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

Comment: so console.log your `err` not the string "error" and you will get more info about the error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `dataType: "json"`? You should also try running `JSON.stringify()` on your object before posting.